# How do I safely cancel a Task?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

So I have this task, that starts on a click of a button and I was wondering, how do I safetly cancel the cycle of this Task?

```
private async Task RunAsync()
{
    PerformanceCounter counter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", pServer.ProcessName, true);
    Random r = new Random();
    while (true)
    {
        float pct = counter.NextValue() / 10f;
        ServerCPU = pct.ToString("0.0");
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }
}
```

After I click the button which starts the cycle of the task, how would I cancel it?

Comment: use a `CancellationToken`

Answer (score 3):

Unlike when dealing with `Thread`s you can't cancel/abort a `Task` without its cooperation. That's where `CancellationToken` and `CancellationTokenSource` come into play.

You should pass `CancellationToken` into `RunAsync` and check if cancellation was requested explicitly, when it makes sense. In your example I'd probably do that in every iteration:

```
private async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken ct)
{
    PerformanceCounter counter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", pServer.ProcessName, true);
    Random r = new Random();
    while (true)
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        float pct = counter.NextValue() / 10f;
        ServerCPU = pct.ToString("0.0");
        await Task.Delay(2000, ct);
    }
}
```

On the callers site you should use `CancellationTokenSource`. It will give you a `Token` to pass into `RunAsync` as well as a way to trigger cancellation:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
RunAsync(cts.Token);

// when you want to cancel it the task:
cts.Cancel();
```

You can read more on that pattern in [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads).

Comment: You could also pass the `CancellationToken` into the `Task.Delay` call.

Comment: You really shouldn't ever cancel a thread, even though you can. It is a bad thing to do.

Comment: Why not just check `ct.IsCancellationRequested` and `exit` the loop? Why `.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`?

Comment: @Enigmativity "You really shouldn't ever cancel a thread, even though you can. It is a bad thing to do." - why?

Comment: @MineR - Calling `.Abort()` on a thread can cause the .NET run-time to enter an undefined state, thus potentially causing all other threads within the current `AppDomain` to no behave as expected. Calling `.Abort()` should only be used when trying to forcibly crash out of your entire app.